# Navbar height when Including input through `bslib` helper functions in R Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am trying to put a regular shiny input in the right side of a `navbarPage` but having some issues.  When I do not include the input (the `selectInput` in this case) the height of the navbar is smaller and compact, but when I do include the input, the height of the navbar grows to ~85px and the components are not aligned.  I have been struggling with this for some time and my research has not netted me any wins.  Can somebody help point me in the right direction?

## Screenshot

[image]

## Code

Here is the example code I put together for the above screenshot.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(bslib)

ui <- navbarPage(
    theme = bs_theme(version = 5, bootswatch = 'sandstone'),
    tags$style(type = 'text/css', 'body {padding-top: 70px;}'),

    title = 'Test', 
    id = 'Test',
    fluid = TRUE,
    useShinydashboard(),
    tabPanel('Panel One',
       sidebarLayout(
         sidebarPanel(
           HTML('There once was a man')
         ),
         
         # Show a plot of the generated distribution
         mainPanel(
           HTML('from Nantucket')
         )
      )
    ),
    nav_spacer(),
    nav_item(
          selectInput('view_options_auto_refresh_rate', '',
                      choices = list(
                        'No Auto Refresh' = Inf,
                        '1 Minute Refresh' = 60,
                        '10 Seconds Refresh' = 10,
                        '5 Seconds Refresh' = 5,
                        '1 Second Refresh' = 1
                      ),
                      selected = Inf
          )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I did find that I do not have the same issue with checkboxes or actionbuttons.  Just the selectinput.

This is a cross-post from the RShiny forums (https://community.rstudio.com/t/navbar-height-when-including-input-through-bslib-helper-functions/144970).  I have had the question there for for a bit with views but no answers.  It was my hope that posting here might broaden the audience.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your style to this one

```r
    tags$style(HTML(
        '
        .nav.navbar-nav .form-group.shiny-input-container {margin-bottom: 0; height: 38px;}
        .nav.navbar-nav .form-group.shiny-input-container > label {display: inline;}
        '
    )),
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that.  I was finding something similar but yours was much cleaner.